# How to handle 'IN' case in SQL Statement with the way of Parameterized Query?

Tags: java, sql, spring, db2

To avoid SQL injection attacks in my project, I'm attempting access database with Parameterized Query way. Right now I know how to handle equal case like below (With Spring JdbcTemplate):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?"
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 
                   new UserRowMapper(), 
                   new Object[]{"%admin%", "%password%"});
```

Above code runs no problem, but I had no idea how to handle the 'IN' case, following is my case, and it works failed:

```
String sql = 
   "SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ? AND CLASS_ID IN (?)"
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, 
                   new UserRowMapper(), 
                   new Object[]{"%admin%", "%password%", "1,2,3"});
```

Anybody give me guidance? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using, and which language (C#, Java, VB.Net, Turbo Pascal)?

Comment: I'm using DB2 and with Java language (Spring JdbcTemplate), thanks for reply.

Comment: If NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is best for this case?

Comment: You can build your query to have parameters inside the IN clause from java. See this question in C#: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create a List and pass it as 3rd parameter. Also You need to use `LIKE` in place of `=` in first two column filters.

```
List<Integer> classIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
classIds.add(1);
classIds.add(2);
classIds.add(3);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE "+
              "USERNAME LIKE ? AND PASSWORD LIKE ? AND CLASS_ID IN (?)";
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new Object[]{"%admin%", "%password%", classIds},
                                                         new UserRowMapper());
```

Please note: Here is the syntax:

```
public List query(String sql, Object[] args, RowMapper rowMapper) 
             throws DataAccessException
```

EDIT:  Please try `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` as bwlow:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE "+
           "USERNAME LIKE :uname AND PASSWORD LIKE :passwd AND CLASS_ID IN (:ids)";
 Map<String, Object> namedParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
 namedParameters.put("uname", "%admin%);
 namedParameters.put("passwd", "%password%");
 namedParameters.put("ids", classIds);
 List result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, namedParameters, 
                                                             new UserRowMapper());
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I follow your way to do it got below error: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT* FROM PFRAS.USER_PROFILE WHERE USERNAME LIKE ? AND PASSWORD LIKE ? AND ID IN (?)]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.io: [jcc][1091][10824][3.57.82] 数据转换无效：参数实例 [1, 35] 对于所请求的转换无效。 ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815

Comment: Sorry, I use a Chinese-version DB2, some message may makes you confused.

Comment: @BradyChu: I updated the answer. Basically, RowMapper is third argument in `query()` method and you were using as second. Pleas swap and try.

Comment: the same exception encounters also.

Comment: @BradyChu: What is the data type of CLASS_ID column? Also you are using   `%...%` in the param then you should use `LIKE` not `=`. Updated the answer.

Comment: Data type for the CLASS_ID (IN Case) is Integer

Comment: Can a Integer-type column use LIKE? Anyway, I will have a try

Comment: @BradyChu: I used the like for other two columns i.e. USERNAME & PASSWORD, not for CLASS_ID. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question: I use LIKE for USERANEM & PASSWORD no problem. The issue point is at how to handle CLASS_ID.

Comment: @BradyChu: I think CLASS_ID handling was fixed by using the `List<Integer>` and issue was coming because of `=` in `UserName` and `Password`. Did you try  it as suggested in the updated answer? Is it still failing??

Comment: Yes, I tried by 'SELECT * FROM T_USER WHERE USERNAME LIKE ? AND PASSWORD LIKE ? AND ID IN (?)'. But still failed.

Comment: @BradyChu: Added another way using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate`. Hope that helps.

Comment: This a good suggestion with namedParameterJdbcTemplate. But it should be approved by my PM, I have no right to change the architecture of project. Thanks! Yogendra Singh!

Comment: @BradyChu: You know your workplace better but I don't think using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate` in place of `jdbcTemplate` template is an architectural change :) Both are part of same `Spring Framework`.

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1. Generate different JDBC queries for each length of the IN LIST, and parameterize each INDIVIDUAL item, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337792/573261)
2. For small tables, you can cheat and use a LIKE statement, e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/337817/573261)
3. Use a SPLIT function (anti-LISTAGG) to turn the delimited list into individual rows of one column each, and JOIN against it. [Example SPLIT function](http://www.dbforums.com/db2/1672833-splitting-row-mulitple-columns.html)

   - You'll parameterize the argument to the function as a single string